# Rotations and prime numbers. What's the pattern?

Tags: prime-numbers, transformation, rotations

I labeled a few lines and thought about rotating a three dimensional shape whose shadow is the picture below. I'm rotating counter-clockwise.

For two lines, labeled $1$ and $2$ I found that it takes $3$ moves to get back to the original configuration.

For three lines, I found that it takes $7$ moves to recover the initial setup.

For four lines, I found that it takes $13$ moves to recover the initial configuration.

> Q: Is there a pattern for the sequence? I'd like to be able to calculate the nth term. So far I have $3,7,13.$

So for $n=3$ lines the full representation would consist of these $7$ steps:

$(1,2,3)\to(1,3,2)\to(3,1,2)\to(3,2,1)\to(3,1,2)\to(1,3,2)\to(1,2,3)$

For $n=2$ the $3$ steps would be:

$(1,2)\to(2,1)\to(1,2)$

[image]

Comment: I am guessing each line will cross each of the other lines twice during the rotation. So that is $n(n-1)$ crossings; & you are then double counting the first and last configurations ... so that makes $\color{red}{n^2+n+1}$ ... & it is just a fluke that the first three values are prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the solution you desire is $n(n-1)+1=n^2-n+1$ steps for $n$ lines. This is because every one of the $n$ lines passes every other one of the $(n-1)$ lines during a single rotation and the first step has to be added. For example we have:
$$\begin{array}
{|r|r|}
\hline n&f(n)\\
\hline 1&1\\
\hline 2&3\\
\hline 3&7\\
\hline 4&13\\
\hline 5&21\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: So the shadow of the object is a permutation, but there's no actual reordering of the elements for the object itself

Comment: @Ultradark The elements on the object are stationary with respect to the object but obviously the shadow of the points on the plane below move with respect to the plane.